# VBA Filtering Year

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code shown below. The first time I filter, it works fine. However the second time, it does not. The filtered column contains years.

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If wSheet.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0) <> wSheet.Range("A1").Offset(i + 1, 0) Then
        WellName = wSheet.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0)
        Set rng = wSheet.Range("A1", Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Name
        L_top = wSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
        L_bot = wSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
        LastRowFilter = wSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        LastColumnFilter = wSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

        For j = 1 To LastRowFilter
            If Year(wSheet.Range("B1").Offset(j, 0)) <> Year(wSheet.Range("B1").Offset(j + 1, 0)) Then
                ReportYear = Year(wSheet.Range("B1").Offset(j, 0))
                Set rng2 = wSheet.Range("B1", Cells(LastRowFilter, LastColumnFilter))
                rng2.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria2:=ReportYear
                L_top = wSheet.Range("B2:B" & LastRowFilter).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
                L_bot = wSheet.Range("B2:B" & LastRowFilter).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count

            End If
        Next

    End If
 Next
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: is actually not an error. but it seems to hide anything. 1st filtering is successful, but when i do 2nd it will hide anything. thx

Comment: is there any ways to do it? I already try to record macros but it still doesnt works

Comment: Is the name of your workbook equal to one of the years in the column you are filtering? Also, what do you want to filter for the second time around?

Comment: first filtering (column A) is about name, it works. Then secondly (column b) i want to filter on year. The data format on column B is on date (dd/mm/yyyy), then i want to filter it based on year so i take Year().

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your issue is your second filter (it seems like the initial filter should cause and error, but if it ain't broke don't fix it :) ). The problem is with the following lines:

```
ReportYear = Year(wSheet.Range("B1").Offset(j, 0))
Set rng2 = wSheet.Range("B1", Cells(LastRowFilter, LastColumnFilter))
rng2.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria2:=ReportYear
```

You are setting `ReportYear` equal to the year you want to filter on (makes sense), but then you are trying to filter on values that equal that year. This seems to make sense logically, but remember that the column contains dates, not years. Not knowing anything else about your code (so apologies for any other errors), this seems to work on my simple tests:

```
ReportYear = Year(wSheet.Range("B1").Offset(j, 0))
Set rng2 = wSheet.Range("B1", Cells(LastRowFilter, LastColumnFilter))
rng2.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= ">=" & DateSerial(ReportYear, 1, 1), _
               Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & DateSerial(ReportYear, 12, 31)
```

This uses your `ReportYear` value but turns the filter into the form "Show me all dates between January 1 and December 31 of `ReportYear`". I agree that this seems a bit inelegant (I'm sure one of the gurus here has a much shorter solution), but it may work in your situation.

Comment: @mr.lumpy Sounds good - happy to help troubleshoot if it doesn't work out.